# My ListView's onItemClickListener() not working when adding WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-listview, focus, onitemclicklistener

When I attach `WebView` to `ListView` then my `onItemClickListener()` of `WebView` stops working. I know that this is problem of focus of `WebView`. But I set:

- in xml of `WebView`:

  ```
  android:clickable="false"  
  android:focusable="false"  
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
  ```
- as well as in adapter class:

  ```
  webview.setFocusable(false);     
  webview.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); 
  webview.versedata.setEnabled(false); 
  webview.setClickable(false);
  ```
- also in main activity:

  ```
  listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
  ```

but still my `onItemClickListener()` is not working. Any suggestions please?

Comment: have you tried implementing onClickListener method in the getView() method of adapter?

Comment: no i didnt tried but what can i do there in getview() method.If i created onclicklistner of webview in adapter then when i click on webview in the list then it calls.but my problem is onitemclicklistner of listview not working.Thanks for help dear @MohitMehta

Comment: I meant to say have you tried to implement onClickListener with convertView in getView() e.g. convertView.setOnClickListener() ?

Comment: @MohitMehta.. thanx for your lovely answer...your trick is reaaly nice but this is same as list.I register
convertView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) context); and in my activity  i didnot get the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
to add your xml main layout

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 

Example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<WebView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement `setOnClickListener` in `getView()` method of in the class derived from BaseAdapter class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //your code
        }
    });

    return convertView; 
}
```

Comment: actually the problem is that i am showing HTML color text having html span tag in web which comes from web.So when user click on that text in webview then i want to perfoem some action,Your code is correct i am getting view when user click outside the webview text.But i want when user click on webtext then also i get view but i am not getting view when i click on text.

Comment: @DEVENDRA do you mean clicking on webview it works but it contains some text and clicking on this text it doesn't, right? or clicking on webview is not work?

Comment: @DEVENDRA have you also tried this in getView() method?  WebView MyWebView = (WebView)convertView.findViewById(id.yourwebview); MyWebView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){});

Comment: i develop this by using ontouchlistner of webview because onclicklistner not working in webview.But thanx for ... you are really helpful.

Comment: @DEVENDRA Also thank you too as I didn't know that onclicklistner doesn't work with webview.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414),It turns out that list item click events will never be received for list items with views that can either handle click events or can gain focus.

try inserting these two lines in the ACTIVITY(DONT PUT THE PROPERTIES IN THE LAYOUT)

wv.setFocusable(false);
wv.setClickable(false);

Comment: try inserting these two lines in the ACTIVITY(DONT PUT THE PROPERTIES IN THE LAYOUT)